# Async method call running synchronously even with await operator

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am trying to call this async method from a console application. I was expecting the part "a" of my method to run asynchronously while the execution awaits for the ReturnsString() but that is not the case, everything seems to be executed synchronously. I am failing to understand why.

sorry for my bad english.

[dotnet fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKC0HJ)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlx0a.png)

```
public class AsyncAwaitExe3
{
    public async Task<string> DoAsync()
    {
        string toReturn = "";
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here A");
        //a
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"inside for {i}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        //b
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here B");
        toReturn = await ReturnsString();

        //c
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here C");
        return toReturn;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReturnsString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here D");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("I'm here E");
        return "sharp sword";
    }
}



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncAwaitExe3 exe3 = new AsyncAwaitExe3();

        Console.WriteLine(exe3.DoAsync());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You've missed ```await``` before ```exe3.DoAsync()``` It returns a task it should be like ```Console.WriteLine(await exe3.DoAsync());```. Make sure you make ```Main``` asynchronous as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section a is synchronous code-- there is nothing about it that returns a task while it continues to run. If you want it to be async, you can break it into a different, async method. Then wait for both to complete using `Task.WhenAll`.

Also, you have to using `Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`. `Task.Delay` returns a task which you can await; `Thread.Sleep` just blocks the thread synchronously.

```
async Task RunSectionA()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm here A");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"inside for {i}");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

public async Task<string> DoAsync()
{
    var taskA = RunSectionA();
    var taskB = ReturnsString();

    await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);
    return await taskB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I was under the impression that async-await would offer me a level of abstraction from having to deal with Tasks manually. Although I understand for specific cases I might need to deal with Tasks directly, but for this requirement, I would assume is a very common one, I would expect there would be anything async-await could offer. Am I wrong thinking this would be the case? thanks

Comment: @ElaineBel You need to move over fully to asynchronous code, it's usually a bad idea to only do it partially. You may want to read this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

Comment: A Task *is* an abstraction. By working with Tasks you avoid having to work with threads, continuations, and in many cases (depending on the synchronization context) common concurrency issues are worked out for you as well. But you need the Task because you need some notion of waiting for the code to run to its completion (and possibly capturing its exceptions).